# Confused about Hyper-V checkpoints

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v

I use Hyper-V on windows 8.1 to set up test environments.

My checkpoint tree looks like this

```
Base
  +Test1
    >Now
  +Test2
  +Test3
```

Since these are test environments I normally don't want to keep changes when moving from one environment to another. i.e. I just `Apply` the checkpoint I want to move to.

The confusion appears when I want to keep changes in one environment. Lets say my tree looks like this:

```
Base
  +Test1
    >Now
  +Test2
    +Changes
  +Test3
```

My questions are:

- How do I merge the `Changes` checkpoint into `Test2`? Do I just `Delete` it?
- Lets say I don't need the `Test3` environment anymore. How do I remove it? Will `Delete` merge it with `Base`

Currently I merge the changes like this but it seems too complicated:

1. `Apply` the `Changes` checkpoint

   ```
   Base
     +Test1
     +Test2
       +Changes
         >Now
     +Test3
   ```
2. `Delete Checkpoint Subtree` on `Test2`

   ```
   Base
     >Now
     +Test1
     +Test3
   ```
3. Create a new checkpoint and rename it `Test2`

   ```
   Base
     +Test2
       >Now
     +Test1
     +Test3
   ```

I always create and `Apply` checkpoints when the VM is shut down. `Delete` and `Apply` refers to the context menu choices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2009/04/15/what-happens-when-i-delete-a-snapshot-hyper-v.aspx) article and now I understand it.

The important point for my understanding is that checkpoints are always merged **downstream** (parent is merged into child).

If there are no checkpoints downstream (`Now` is considered a checkpoint in this context), the checkpoint is just deleted without merge.

What confused me was that differential disks, and undo-disks in Virtual PC, merge upstream (child is merged into parent).

So the answer to my questions above are:

> - How do I merge the Changes checkpoint into Test2?

Not possible since you can't merge upstream!
What is possible is to merge `Test2` into `Changes` by `Deleting` `Test2`!.

```
Base
  +Test1
    >Now
  +Changes
  +Test3
```

> - Lets say I don't need the Test3 environment anymore. How do I remove it?

`Test3` don't have any downstream checkpoints so it can just be `Deleted` If it has downstream checkpoints which should also be removed, use `Delete Chekpoint subtree`.